# Autofac in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

As a newbie to Autofac, I'm trying to figure out how to register my Repository for my Controllers.  The Repository takes a web service in its constructor to communicate with the server.  This application is multi-tenant and the tenant name is accessed in the MVC route data. Since I can't access the route data within global.asax like most of the examples, where do I inject this dependency and what would the code look like?

Comment: Just to be clear, the Repository implementation depends on the URL the user visits (ex http://mysite.com/tenant/account/edit)?

Comment: That is correct.  I use that tenant name along with a security token to connect to the web service the Repository depends on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`Autofac.Features.Indexed.IIndex<K, V>`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices) type which allows you to build a mapping of keys to implementations.

```
public enum RepositoryWebServices { ServiceA, ServiceB, ServiceC }

builder.RegisterType<MyServiceA>().Keyed<IWebService>(RepositoryWebServices.ServiceA);
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceB>().Keyed<IWebService>(RepositoryWebServices.ServiceB);
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceC>().Keyed<IWebService>(RepositoryWebServices.ServiceC );

public MyRepository : IRepository
{
  IIndex<RepositoryWebServices, IWebService> _webServices;

  public MyRepository(IIndex<RepositoryWebServices, IWebService> webServices)
  {
    _webServices = webServices;
  }

  public UseWebService(string tenant)
  {
    IWebService webService = _webServices[(RepositoryWebServices)Enum.Parse(typeof(RepositoryWebServices), tenant)];

    // use webService
  }
}
```

Comment: Todd, thanks this is close to what I'm after.  Where would be the best place to call UseWebService?  I basically need to call this once to initialize the web service and then my repository methods can do what they need to do.  The problem is I need the route data to get the tenant so I don't think I can do this in global.asax.  Right now, I call UseWebService by overriding the Initialize method in a base controller because I can get to the route data.  This works but just doesn't feel right.